# usage of string tokenizer

Tags: c, string

i have a string like this..

/home/Abcd/Pradeep/Jack.sh

/home/Abcd/Pradeep/Paul/Kill.sh

I need to take Jack.sh and Kill.sh alone from these strings. there can be many / in the string.

How to do this using strtok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `strtok` for this. Just use [`strrchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strrchr.html) to find the last `'/'` character. Your filename starts one character after that.

Comment: Unless there are no '/' characters in the string. Remember to check for null :-)

Comment: though, posix system will have the basename() function, doing pretty much all the work for him !

Answer (score 1):

From the path name style, it looks like it is a *nix system.
You can use the command `basename` which does the same thing. 
If you want to use it in a c program, try `man 3 basename` in your system to get the documentation.